Load data from S3 to Snowflake, overwrite vs using stream
I'm trying to load files from S3 to Snowflake using copy into commands. The pipeline is scheduled using Airflow. Each day there would be new files (e.g. source_20240501.csv). In order to rerun a certain day's job, suppose an updated version of source_20240501.csv file was uploaded, currently the job deletes data where date_key=20240501 in the table and use copy into to load the updated data again.
My question is, is this the way to go, or can I use Snowflake stream to do this? How do I use stream when sometimes there's no PK in the source data? The source data could be like the sample below:
Code      sec_code    score 
1000       1001        a
2000       2001        b
2000       2002        c


to me this looks like full data load scenario, because you are deleting the data from table and reloading the data. If you think that this is how pipeline works then what your code is doing right. But  assume this is delta data load scenario, lets say you are staging this changed data into stage table temporarily and next stage table is for full snapshot then it makes sense to load this changed data to next stage table either using stream.
